# Best practices for Atlassian Bamboo job build artifacts and generated static files

Tags: python, css, less, bamboo, django-compressor

I'd like to get advice on how to properly manage Bamboo build and resulting artifacts with following package release to different machine. Static files, specifically compressed css/js by django-compressor are currently generated on the build server and then all artifacts are copied to the target machine. I'm not entirely sure that it is the best approach, it's probably just better to exclude css/js from artifacts completely and run compression again on new host. Just looking for other ideas.